# Undeclared Identifier C Programming in Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

So I'm creating a simple program, and I usually use the GNU compiler.

However, this time I chose to use Visual C++ for developing in C.

I've set up my project correctly, changing the settings to make it compile in C. The code is very simple:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Hey!");
    int x = 9;
    printf("%d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

If I compiled this using Code::Blocks IDE and the GNU compiler, it would work, but for some reason it doesn't work in Visual C++. I keep getting these errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VC++ 2010 only implements C89/C90, not the newer C standards that allow variable declarations after other statements inside of a function body. To fix it, move the declaration of `x` to the beginning of `main`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 9;
    printf("Hey!");
    printf("%d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I personally don't like it, but the course I'm taking requires me to.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension to .cpp

Comment: "Sometimes", the question is more than read it literally, word by word... if this doesn't solve his trouble, he can just skip it... Every once in a while, there is people who can't tell the difference between ANSI C, ISO C, C89, C90, C99, C11, etc. You can cripple the Microsoft ANSI extensions adding /Za into compiler command line.

Comment: "*However, this time I chose to use Visual C++ for developing in C. I've set up my project correctly, changing the settings to make it compile in C.*" This seems extremely unambiguous to me. ;-] (Note: I'm not the downvoter.)